# What regularization of singularity means?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, singularity-theory, singularity

I have this function,

$$F(r) =  \frac{1}{r^{6}-1}$$

What does regularization of the singularity mean? I think we can add a small imaginary part to remove the singularity like given below.
$$F(r) = \frac{1}{r^{6}-1+i 0^{+}}$$

How this helps when evaluating following integral.

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{r^{6}-1+i 0^{+}}dr$$

Comment: I mean, if you wanted to regularize that integral, you could just use
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^\pm}\int_{-1}^1F(r+i\epsilon)~\mathrm dr$$

Comment: What does regularization do? Can you explain the effects of it?